# Angular 4 CLI, WebPack, switching bootstrap theme dynamically for the entire website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I want to provide users with a button to change the theme of the entire website. I am using bootstrap ".scss" files for everything.
Here is what I have done:

I have "dark-styles.scss" and "light-styles.scss" in "src/styles" folder. Both of these files override the classes and methods that I need to override and also import the "bootstrap.scss" from "node-module" for the defaults. When I provide any of these file to the application through ".angular-cli.json" like below; it works perfectly.

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
        "../src/styles/dark-styles.scss"
      ],
```

or,

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
        "../src/styles/light-styles.scss"
      ],
```

If I provide the dark the theme is dark and if I provide light the theme is light.

But what I want to achieve is dynamically allow the users to change the theme. Hence, based on other answers in stackoverflow; I accessed the "document" in my app component which is also my root component. It gives me access to the entire html page where I have a link tag which I can set from the app-component.

HTML file

```
<head>
<link id="theme" type="text/scss" rel="stylesheet" src="">
</head>
<body>
content .....
</body>
```

Angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css"
      ],
```

App-Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      currentTheme: string;

      constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.currentTheme = 'dark';
        this.document.getElementById('theme').href = '../styles/dark-styles.scss';
      }

      handelChangeTheme(event) {
        if (this.currentTheme === 'dark') {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').href = '../styles/light-styles.scss';
          this.currentTheme = 'light';
          console.log('light');
        } else {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').href = '../styles/dark-styles.scss';
          this.currentTheme = 'dark';
          console.log('dark');
        }
      }
    }
```

While triggering the event "handleChangeTheme" the href for the #theme changes in the html file. But it does not update or apply the styles. I understand that it has something to do with WebPack and the way it compiles the scss files. Has anybody faced the similar situation or know the solution to this issue. Thanks

Comment: I guess you'd have to compile both scss files and make them available for the app to select from (i.e. pack them into your webapp)

Comment: @ochi ... tried that too ... didn't work. While doing so, the default bootstrap is applied the override are all rejected.

Comment: Did you solve it? I was assigned to do the same exact thing. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Nope I put it aside for now ..... it is so easy to achieve this in material

Comment: Webpack uses a processor to convert Sass -> CSS. Assuming the paths and file type are correct, this seems like the same technique used by Material doc (paint bucket at the top right, selecting a theme updates href of `link.style-manager-theme`: https://material.angular.io/)

Answer (score 8):

I just done your example locally and seems to be issue with `type="text/scss"` after i changed it to `text/css` it starts working. I thought firstly that you need to recreate element but issue seems to be with type

Since its theme i would recommend you to use compiled css versions of those files put them into `assets` folder and angular-cli will copy them on `serve` and `build`

In addition When you refer to scss in your angular its compiled with webpack to css.

Comment: I started a bounty on this question because I had the same problem. I ended solving it using another approach, more precisely, something similar to this: https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-theming-neverending-story/

Comment: @MarcusVinicius - a more detailed explanation of your approach would help. Did you pre-compile the scss to css (as suggested by Volodymyr Bilyachat) - does this happen using angular-cli itself or you had to add some manual node-sass commands to get htis working....and how did you switch themes (using link? as proposed by Virodh originally?)

Comment: @RafiAliKhan, I added an answer with a more detailed explanation on how I managed to get dynamic theme working.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get dynamic theme working in Angular 4 + Bootstrap by using the following approach:

**Defined theme colors by using a map:**

```
$themes: (
    alpha: (
        primary: #2b343e,
        info: #3589c7,
        top-color: #000000,
        top-font-color: #ffffff,
        ...
    ),
    beta: (
        primary: #d2a444,
        info: #d2a444,
        top-color: #ffffff,
        top-font-color: #000000,
        ...
    )
)
```

**Then, created the following mixin to output colors for each theme name and given properties**:

```
@mixin theme($property, $key, $themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $colors in $themes {
    &.theme-#{$theme},
    .theme-#{$theme} & {
      #{$property}: map-get($colors, $key);
    }
  }
}
```

I used *mixins* to control individual properties:

```
@mixin color($arguments...) {
  @include themify('color', $arguments...);
}

@mixin background-color($arguments...) {
  @include themify('background-color', $arguments...);
}
```

**For each "themeable" component, I had to use the *mixins* above when declaring properties:**

```
.page-top {
    @include background-color('top-color');
    @include color('top-font-color');    
    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
    ...    
}
```

**The CSS output would be something like:**

```
.page-top {
    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
    ...    
}

.page-top.theme-alpha,
.theme-alpha .page-top {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.page-top.theme-beta,
.theme-beta .page-top {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
```

**And finally, to make the theme available, you have to control the theme class in some parent component:**

```
<!-- class="theme-alpha" -->
<main themeChange>
    <page-top></page-top>
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <page-bottom></page-bottom>
</main>
```

The `themeChange` directive could be written like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[themeChange]'
})
export class ThemeChange implements OnInit {
    @HostBinding('class') classes: string;
    private _classes: string[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {        
        // grab the theme name from some config, variable or user input
        this.classesString = myConfig.theme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After couple of hours trying, I finally get **bootstrap theme switcher** to work. Here is my solution:

1. Instead of using bootswatch.scss, download compiled version for each theme, put them in same asset folder and rename the file accordingly.

[image: save compiled css]

2. Add this line to index.html. choose default theme:

   ```
   < link id="theme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/theme_slate_bootstrap.min.css">
   ...
   ...
   <body class="theme-slate">
   ...
   ```

3. Currently setting up shortcut to switch theme in app.component. So this is app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
    selector: 'apps',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        private currentTheme: string = 'slate';

        constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

        ngOnInit() {}

        theme(type) {
            this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'theme-'+this.currentTheme);
            this.currentTheme = type;
            this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'theme-'+this.currentTheme);
            this.document.getElementById('theme').href = '/assets/css/theme_'+type+'_bootstrap.min.css';
        }
    }
```

4. Buttons to switch the themes

   ```
   <div style="display:block; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; text-align:right; z-index:100000;">
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="theme('slate')">Slate</button>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="theme('yeti')">Yeti</button>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="theme('darkly')">Darkly</button>
   </div>
   ```
5. Add this custom file in angular.json

   ```
   "styles": [
       "src/assets/scss/custom.scss"
   ],
   ```
6. custom.scss - add your custom code to work here

   ```
   $themes: (
       slate: (
           name: 'slate',
           primary: #3A3F44,
           secondary: #7A8288,
           ...
       ),
       yeti: (
           name: 'yeti',
           primary: #008cba,
           secondary: #eee,
           ...
       ),
       darkly: (
           name: 'darkly',
           primary: #008cba,
           secondary: #eee,
           ...
       ),
   );

   /*
   * Implementation of themes
   */
   @mixin themify($themes) {
       @each $theme, $map in $themes {
           .theme-#{$theme} & {
           $theme-map: () !global;
           @each $key, $submap in $map {
               $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
               $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
           }
           @content;
           $theme-map: null !global;
           }
       }
   }

   @function themed($key) {
       @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
   }


   * {
       @include themify($themes) {
           // custom theme to your needs. Add here
           @if themed('name') == 'slate' {
           }


           @if themed('name') == 'yeti' {
           }


           @if themed('name') == 'darkly' {
           }


           // Below will effect all themes
           .btn, .form-control, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu {
               border-radius: 0;
           }

           // This is just example to code. When switching theme, primary button theme should changed. Below code is not required. 
           .btn-primary {
               background-color: themed('primary');
               border-color: themed('primary');
           }

       }
   }
   // ***********************************************************************

   @import "custom-additional-classes";
   ```

Hope this help everyone who seeking solution for bootstrap themes switcher