# How to dynamically change theme color in Angular CLI app

Tags: angular, typescript, themes, angular-cli, angular5

I created an app using Angular cli and now wanting to change the theme, maybe base on custumer will have different theme, color scheme at least.

I found some solutions but only help to change the main style.less file in src folder. While in my app I break into small components and each components will have their css file and I want each component to get affected if I changed the theme.

Been thinking about moving all the css into one file but it sounds stupid and might be very complicated with the ::ng-deep stuff

Anyone had ideas about this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705611/angular-4-cli-webpack-switching-bootstrap-theme-dynamically-for-the-entire-web

Answer (score 0):

For this I use a combination of sessionStorage and [ngStyle] to set the style of the component also use it for front-size and stuff.

`[ngStyle]="{'font-family': settings.fontFamily, 'font-size': settings.fontSize}"`

For color maybe have to add this on every component you use.

Comment: Well I use this on the body and apply to the whole application. But yeah for multiple different components this can be a bad practice. Also change it with a setting page in the maincomponent and set it again in settings and SessionStorage.

Comment: Ya, this work for small application but application big then this solution not work :)