# change themes or skins with bootstrap-4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have an usecase where on button toggle, i need to change my skins/themes. I am not sure how to properly achieve them in bootstrap 4(have gone through their docs). My skins/themes changes involve btn-colors, fonts, background-color, hover-color, box-shadow and active-color.
I have one idea: To create sass functions for these property and return them based on css-selector. Like I could have dark and light selectors attached to it, and get proper values returned.(Inspired from Angular Material).
Or is there any other way to properly do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction you could go is JS/jQuery. This isn't pointing to Bootstrap 4 but can be modified to do so.

I did find a related question with SASS you might find relevant, [switching bootstrap theme dynamically for the entire website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705611/angular-4-cli-webpack-switching-bootstrap-theme-dynamically-for-the-entire-web?rq=1)
.

---

The basic flow is...

Give your link to your CSS an ID:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="ref-css">
```

You could use a checkbox toggle:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Light" data-off="Dark">
```

Write some jQuery to toggle the css file on change:

```
  $(function() {
      $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $("#ref-css").attr("href", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/united/bootstrap.min.css");
        }else{
          $("#ref-css").attr("href", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/slate/bootstrap.min.css");
        }
      })
    })
```

---

Here's the complete HTML & jQuery so you have something to work with. It also has a dropbox in the top right corner to choose from various styles:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#theme-button ul a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') != 'current') {
      var urlbeg = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/'
      var urlend = '/bootstrap.min.css'
      var themeurl = urlbeg + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + urlend;
      var link = $('link[rel="stylesheet"][href$="/bootstrap.min.css"]').attr('href', themeurl);

      $('#theme-button ul a[name="current"]').text($(this).text());
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $("#ref-css").attr("href", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/united/bootstrap.min.css");
    } else {
      $("#ref-css").attr("href", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/slate/bootstrap.min.css");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- To switch themes, go to https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/?theme=0 -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="ref-css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Bootswatch Theme Changer</a>
      <div class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li id="theme-button" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Change Theme <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
            <li><a href="#" name="current">Cerulean</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="cerulean">Cerulean</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="cosmo">Cosmo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="cyborg">Cyborg</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="darkly">Darkly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="flatly">Flatly</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sample Btn</a>
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-event" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Light" data-off="Dark">

  <div class="box effect1">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  </div>

  <p>Vestibulum sit amet ipsum lacus. Aliquam nisl enim&hellip; tristique tempus placerat at, posuere in lectus. Suspendisse potenti cras molestie, risus a enim convallis vitae luctus libero lacinia. Nulla vel magna sit amet dui <a href='#'>lobortis</a>    commodo vitae vel nulla. Nunc iaculis risus vel orci ornare dignissim sed vitae nulla. Aliquam tincidunt velit sit amet <a href='#'>ante hendrerit</a> tempus. Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas, mauris est viverra nibh, iaculis pretium
    sem orci aliquet mauris. </p>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Nunc iaculis risus vel orci ornare dignissim sed vitae nulla. Vestibulum sit amet ipsum lacus… Suspendisse potenti. Nulla auctor eleifend 23rd of May turpis consequat pharetra.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas, mauris est viverra nibh, <a href='#'>iaculis pretium</a> sem orci aliquet mauris. Maecenas sit <em>amet tellus</em> nec mi gravida posuere non <a href='#'>pretium magna</a>. Curabitur consectetur; faucibus
    nisl ac varius. Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas, mauris est viverra nibh, iaculis pretium sem orci aliquet mauris. Nulla lobortis tempus commodo. </p>
  <h2>Curabitur consectetur</h2>
  <p>Nulla lobortis tempus commodo? Suspendisse potenti. Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas, mauris est viverra nibh (iaculis pretium sem orci aliquet mauris). Suspendisse potenti H<sub>2</sub>0. </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas</li>
    <li>Sed dapibus, lectus sit amet adipiscing egestas</li>
    <li>Vestibulum sit amet ipsum lacus</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Purus lectus venenatis urna</h2>
  <p>Nulla lobortis tempus commodo? Nulla lobortis tempus <strong>commodo</strong>. Fusce ac sodales <code>.generate()</code> magna. Donec tempus tempus tellus, ac lacinia turpis mattis ac. Maecenas sit <q cite='http://www.heydonworks.com'>amet tellus nec mi gravida posuere</q>    non pretium magna. Nunc iaculis risus vel orci ornare dignissim sed vitae nulla. Nulla vel magna sit &mdash; amet dui lobortis commodo &mdash; vitae vel nulla. </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the comment mate. Since we are also looking for angular-workaround , we are looking into more.