# How to change theme of a webapp generated with jhipster dynamically

Tags: angular, spring-boot, webpack, jhipster

I'm using **Jhipster 6.9.1**

I want to change theme of my app to **Dark Mode** dynamically also I've an entity called **Setting**
and a user can have multiple settings.

Example:

```
 User                     |        Setting 
 id | login               |        id  |  key          |  value   |  user_id   
 1  | xxxxx               |        1   |  'DarkMode'   |  true    |  1
 2  | yyyyy               |        2   |  'DarkMode'   |  false   |  2
```

In the other hand, I've two scss  files : **dark-mode.scss** and **light-mode.scss** which is the default theme imported in

> webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss

I've followed many articles that focus in this purpose, also there is a module called **bootswatch**  work only with AngularJS in addition it s deprecated since Jhipster 5 and later

I've tried to use dark-mode.scss in root component as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705611/angular-4-cli-webpack-switching-bootstrap-theme-dynamically-for-the-entire-web)   but the style is not applied unless I import it in vendor.scss

Comment: The instructions about CSS in your link cannot work because JHipster 6 has its own webpack build, it does not use the one from Angular CLI so changes in angular.json have no effect. So vendor.scss is the right way. JHipster 7 will change this. Please edit your question to show some code: vendor.scss, bootswatch line in package.json, your component to switch theme. If you selected a client theme when generating your project you should have almost everything setup except dynamic switch

Comment: i ve tried to convert light-mode.scss to light-mode.css using several online tools and also with node-sass then i ve declared it in maincomponent.ts but it doesn't apply style , same result if i include it in index.html . peter , is there a way to configure webpack like MiniCssExtractPlugin or either to compile scss in jhipster ?